# String#scan not capturing all occurrences

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm facing a very strange behaviour with ruby String#scan method return. I have this code below and I can't find out why "scan" doesn't return 2 elements.

```
str = "10011011001"
regexp = "0110"
p str.scan(/(#{regexp})/)

==> [["0110"]]
```

String "str" clearly contains 2 occurrences of pattern "0110". 
I want to fetch all the occurences of my regexp in str of course.

Comment: You can't obtain overlapping substrings as result (with this kind of pattern). a character is consumed once and for all.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about lookahead regexp. thx.

Comment: I'd use @Casimar's regex, but would like to point out that you don't have to use a regex at all. While we're at it, wouldn't it make more sense to just return the number of substrings `"0110"` in the string, rather than `[["0110"], ["0110"],...]`? Like so: `match = "0110".chars;  "10011011001".each_char.each_cons(4).count { |a| a == match } #=> 2`.

Comment: Thanks Cary but for this problem I need to use regexp to be able to replace parts of that strings afterwords...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that after finding the first result, the regex engine continues its walk at the position *after* this first result. So the zero at the end of the first result can't be reuse for an other result.

The way to get overlapping results is to put your pattern in a lookahead and in a capture group (a lookahead is only a zero-width assertion (a test) and doesn't consume any characters). In this way the regex engine advance always one character at a time and can test all positions in the string even something is captured in the group:

```
(?=(yourpattern))
```

Then your result is in the capture group 1

With your example:

```
p str.scan(/(?=(0110))/)
[["0110"], ["0110"]]
```

Comment: Very nice, as always. A positive lookbehind works as well, of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "10011011001"
match = "0110"

str.chars.each_cons(match.size).map(&:join).select { |cons| cons == match }
```

Should do it.

Comment: this over complicates things a bit and does not utilize a regex at all which seems to be an important part of the question.

Comment: I assumed that the result was the important part (the question is tagged regex, but it doesn't show in the title). The solution with the regex lookahead is quite neat, but it's better to have multiple options than not (imho).